# Does ConcurrentQueue.IsEmpty require a memory barrier?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

When looking into IsEmpty, I noticed this on MSDN:

> However, as this collection is intended to be accessed concurrently, it may be the case that another thread will modify the collection after IsEmpty returns, thus invalidating the result.

Sure this is true, but does this also imply that ConcurrentQueue doesn't use a read barrier when checking if the queue is empty?

I want to have a piece of code that checks in another thread if the concurrent queue is empty. Something like this:

```
while (!queue.IsEmpty)
{
}
```

However.. if ConcurrentQueue doesn't use a read barrier, I'd say we need to add our own memory barrier to ensure we read the right data, like this:

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
while (!queue.IsEmpty)
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
}
```

(BTW: These are just a minimal example to illustrate the case, there's more code in reality).

Is my observation correct? Or does the ConcurrentQueue handle this and does the first implementation work? (e.g. what I would expect from 'Concurrent')?

And what about 'Count'? I can't find the answer on MSDN... Same story?

Comment: So what if it does or doesn't use a memory barrier? By the time you read the returned data, the barrier is history and all bets are off.

Comment: @spender Well, if it doesn't use a read barrier it could loop indefinitely - which is quite a bad thing IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's nothing to do with memory barriers. It's simply got to be the case that something else could nip in and add or remove something to or from the queue just after your test.

You shouldn't really use `IsEmpty`. Use `TryDequeue` instead. Or use a `BlockingCollection`.

You really don't want to start writing code that "locks" the queue while you mess around with `IsEmpty` or `Count`.

(I almost never use `ConcurrentQueue` nowadays, since `BlockingCollection` is so much better, although that does of course depend on what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Yep, if you're testing something prior to operating on it, you're open to concurrency issues. TryDequeue, AddOrUpdate and the like address these issues by removing the need for 2 stage test/commit operations.

Comment: I hardly ever use BlockingCollection nowadays because BufferBlock (and the rest of TPL Dataflow) is so much better ;)

Comment: @spender: We have to support Windows Server 2003 still, and therefore we can't use .Net 4.5, so BufferBlock is zero use to us. :) Unless - is there a version for .Net 4?

Comment: It certainly is. No `await` keyword, can't use the new TPL libraries etc. :(

Comment: @MatthewWatson Of course I'm also using things like TryDequeue; I just want to use IsEmpty to provide users with a synchronization point that waits till everything is synced in another worker thread (that is: if an enqueue breaks that it's fine in this scenario). So what you're basically saying is that I don't have to use memory barriers, correct?

Comment: @StefandeBruijn I'd venture that testing for an empty queue is probably the wrong approach here. Your other thread knows when it has finished. It might be better to communicate that across to the thread you want to wait using a different approach.

Comment: Correct: There's no need to use memory barriers. But also, there's nothing you can do about the fact that the queue could become empty or non-empty just after you've checked `IsEmpty` and before you've acted upon the return value.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Okay thanks. Phew, that means it works as you would implicitly expect. :-) I'll mark your answer as correct, thanks for helping out!